# MySQL operator SELECT how-to get one exact row result from similiar rows?

Tags: php, mysql

i have such 'SEO' rows in simple table **categories (id, name, seo)**:

```
"abc"
"abc 22"
"abc 33"
```

how in MySQL get with this query

```
SELECT id FROM categories WHERE seo='abc' AND LENGTH('abc')='3';"
```

one exact row result "abc" from "abc" without finding "abc 22" and "abc 33"?

Comment: This should work without the LENGTH(...) since seo='abc' will check if the string is exactly seo.

Comment: it's example, without LENGTH i get 3 rows result

Comment: How about your actual select. It is not like you are using `like`

Comment: I don't know which MySQL version or whatever you're running but I just tested this and with or without the `AND LENGTH('abc')='3';` part I get just one result. And all the tutorials and documentations are providing the same info: = means exactly equal. Since `abc 22` or `abc 33` is not equal to abc, the row should not appear in your result.

Comment: you right, i close question, just analized table result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create table stuff
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    seo varchar(100) not null
    -- unique key (seo) not a bad idea
);

insert stuff (seo) values ('abc'),('abc7'),('kitty likes abc'),('abc and more abc'),('kittens');
insert stuff (seo) values ('abc at beginning'),('frogs'),('and at the end abc'),('qwertyabcqwerty');


select id from stuff where seo='abc';
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
+----+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

Here is how `like` behaves:

```
select * from stuff where seo like '%abc';
+----+--------------------+
| id | seo                |
+----+--------------------+
|  1 | abc                |
|  3 | kitty likes abc    |
|  4 | abc and more abc   |
|  8 | and at the end abc |
+----+--------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

select * from stuff where seo like 'abc%';
+----+------------------+
| id | seo              |
+----+------------------+
|  1 | abc              |
|  2 | abc7             |
|  4 | abc and more abc |
|  6 | abc at beginning |
+----+------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

select id,seo from stuff where seo like '%abc%';
+----+--------------------+
| id | seo                |
+----+--------------------+
|  1 | abc                |
|  2 | abc7               |
|  3 | kitty likes abc    |
|  4 | abc and more abc   |
|  6 | abc at beginning   |
|  8 | and at the end abc |
|  9 | qwertyabcqwerty    |
+----+--------------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the exact comparison operator, you can just use:

`SELECT id FROM categories WHERE seo = 'abc';`

There's no need to test for length since you're using `=`.