# How to make a system seach in database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i want to make system search for my site (ADS)

```
$sql->mysql_query(
"SELECT * FROM ads WHERE ads_catgs='".$gettagname."' 
AND ads_Marque LIKE '%$ads_Marque%' 
OR ads_Modèle LIKE '%$ads_Modèle%' 
OR ads_Type_de_carburant LIKE '%$ads_Type_de_carburant%' 
OR ads_Année_Modèle LIKE '%$ads_Année_Modèle%' 
OR ads_Kilométrage LIKE '%$ads_Kilométrage%' 
OR ads_city='".$getcity."' 
AND ads_title LIKE '%$getsearchfor%' 
ORDER BY ads_id DESC") or die($sql->mysql_error());
```

it's work but if I search for a ads title " Test " and ads_Marque "For_Test" .... it's select any ads title "test" and ads_Marque != "For_Test"

(I'm sorry for my bad english )

Comment: is ads_Marque supposed to be exactly =, if so why the like?

Comment: because the input is a text

Comment: course it is. But why add the extra risk if it = to begin with (like you did with = on $gettagname)

Comment: this questions needs to be improved showing 1) the value of your variables, 2) a small dataset, 3) expected results, 4) any query changes with parenthesis. Only then can people authoritatively help you. `Like` can give unexpected results despite its simplicity, as can be seen here in what I wrote earlier today: (http://stackoverflow.com/a/31545517/1816093)

Answer (score 0):

Use `trim` to remove before and after spaces from keyword.

Try

```
$sql->mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ads WHERE ads_catgs='".$gettagname."' AND ads_Marque LIKE '%".trim($ads_Marque)."%' OR ads_Modèle LIKE '%".trim($ads_Modèle)."%' OR ads_Type_de_carburant LIKE '%".trim($ads_Type_de_carburant)."%' OR ads_Année_Modèle LIKE '%".trim($ads_Année_Modèle)."%' OR ads_Kilométrage LIKE '%".trim($ads_Kilométrage)."%' OR ads_city='".$getcity."' AND ads_title LIKE '%".trim($getsearchfor)."%' ORDER BY ads_id DESC") or die($sql->mysql_error());
```